# Finding Top ten most viewed movies using MapReduce program

Tags: mapreduce

While trying to find the top ten most viewed movies with their name (Ascending or Descending order) using MapReduce, I got the below error.

```
"Error: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize any output collector
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:695)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)"
```

I checked similar question and solution was set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb < 2048 but in my case this value is set as mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100. please guide me i m new to MapReduce programming.

Comment: Could you please add more clarity on what you are trying to achieve and the code written for that?

Comment: Thanks gyan. i m able to solve this issue. Actually i added wrong library for Text. i added com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.Text; this library which was causing this issue. later i changed this with org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; and program works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue.

Actually, I added the wrong library for Text.

I added `com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.Text`; this library which was causing this issue. Later I changed this with `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`, and now the program works.